# php allow access to pages to only logged in users

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 pages have html code similar to just example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
html code
</div>

<div>
html code
</div>

<div>
html code
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and have 2 php files login.php and logout.php , is it possible to strict access to the 3 pages only to login users

Comment: For that you have set session

Comment: After login successfully, set user id in session & each page check whether this value exist in session or not.If exist open the page otherwise redirect to login page.

Answer (score 4):

**First**, Put in `header` page this `session_start();`, Ofcourse the `header` page is `included||required` in every php page you have.

**Second**, When the user `Login` using your `Login page`, Put the `sessions` if his data are `valid`

```
<?php
if($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
     $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
}
 ?>
```

In this one we used his `id` inside `session`, Now all you have to do is checking if this `session` is active, If it is not active, You redirect the visitor using `header()` to the `index||404` page like this

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    die(header("location: 404.php"));
}
?>
```

and remove the `!` for `signup & login` pages, Since you don't want a `logged in` user to access the `login` or `register` page again.

**Third**, For `logout` page, Just put

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("location: index.php");
exit();
?>
```

inside it

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you have 3 php files and not html. You need to save those files as .php if you want to manage this using PHP.

Yes you can manage that using a variable or session.

You can redirect the user if they are not logged in. Or, you can show the part of the text and link only if they are logged in.

```
<?php 
    if($logged_in) {
?>
  <a href="hidddenpage">Only for logged in users</a>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use *session* to do it in PHP, it will be like this.

```
$_SESSION(id)
```

You can see some tutorial in google.

Refer the below link http://www.makeitsimple.co.in/PHP_loginexmp.php

Comment: but i have a long html code I used the method in both case loged and non loged can see the codes my html code is <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
 
    <link href="app/views/style/css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    .........